# Questions involving Stacks of cards and a method that's supposed to remove the top cards

Tags: java, stack

I'm working through this assignment at the moment, which i've done most of the work for at this point. It contains 2 packages, one entitled generics where the exception handling classes, interface (StackADT in this case), and stack methods (pop(), peek(), and push()) are located. The other is called lab, where card class in defined and its contents which are rank

```
public String getRankAsString() {
String[] ranks = "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A" 
return ranks[rank];
}
```

and suit

```
public String getSuitAsString() {
String[] suits = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", 
"Hearts", "Spades" };
    return suits[suit];
}
```

equals compares whether or not 2 cards have the same rank and suit

```
    public boolean equals(Card otherCard) {
    return ((rank == otherCard.rank) && 
    (suit == otherCard.suit));
    }

I was supposed to create 2 classes within the lab package, one called LabApp (where the testing would happen) and DiscardPile, a subclass of Stack<T> and would contain a method "discardTopCard",  method called removeTopCards which accepts a reference to a Card object called theCard. This method will allow the user to request that all cards up to and including theCard be removed from the discard pile and returned in an array, thus the return-type of the method is Card[]. This is what I have for removeTopCard atm.

public Card[] removeTopCard(Card otherCard) throws StackEmptyException {
        Card[] theCard = new Card[size()];
        int i = 0;
        boolean check = false;

        if(isEmpty()){ //in the case that there's nothing there
          throw new StackEmptyException("Stack is Empty");
        }
        while(!isEmpty()){ //If it's not empty, pop the top card (unlimited loop that'll need to be broken by a break;)

          Card top = (Card) pop(); //Casts Card to pop, which should remove it
          theCard[i] = top; //removed and returned in an array
          i++; 
          if(top.equals(otherCard)){ //checks if the card's rank and suit are the same and stops the loop if true
            check = true;
            break; //it ends the loop if they're equivalent, all of those cards were set to top
          }
        }
        if(!check){ //if it can't find anything
          throw new StackEmptyException("Card not found");
        }
        Card[] topCards = new Card[i];

        for(int j = 0;j < i; j++){

          topCards[j] = theCard[j]; //set the discarded value array to theCard
        }
        return topCards; //should return the popped numbers
      }
```

I THINK this could work just fine.

In LabApp, the testing method, I currently have

```
import generics.StackFullException;
import generics.StackEmptyException;


public class Lab4App {
       public static void main(String[] args)throws StackFullException, StackEmptyException {
        try {
        DiscardPile<Card> discardPile = null; 
        discardPile = new DiscardPile<Card>();
        discardPile.push(new Card(8));
        discardPile.push(new Card(32));
        discardPile.push(new Card(48));
        discardPile.push(new Card(2));
        discardPile.push(new Card(17));
        discardPile.push(new Card(20)); //removeTopCard should remove all that's above
        discardPile.push(new Card(25));
        discardPile.push(new Card(50));
        discardPile.push(new Card(19));
        discardPile.push(new Card(41)); //10 Cards that must be popped

        for(int i = 0; i < discardPile.getSize(); i++) {
            Card var = discardPile.pop(); //pops the cards that are above
                System.out.println(var.getRankAsString() + " of " + var.getSuitAsString());
        }

        }
        catch (StackEmptyException SEE) {
            System.out.println("StackEmptyException: " + SEE.getMessage());
        }
        catch (StackFullException SFE) {
            System.out.println("StackFullException: " + SFE.getMessage());
       }
}
}
```

It's printing the desired output of

```
4 of Spades
8 of Diamonds
K of Spades
A of Diamonds
9 of Diamonds
6 of Diamonds
4 of Clubs
J of Spades
8 of Hearts
10 of Clubs
```

but it returns

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
```

at the end

I created a default constructor

```
public class DiscardPile<T> extends Stack<T>  { //subclass of its parent Stack
    private T[] data;
    private int size;


    //private static final int maxSize = 52;

    public DiscardPile() throws StackFullException, StackEmptyException {
        //this.data = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
        this.size = 52; //52 is supposed to be the max value
    }
    /**
     * Constructs a new Stack with capacity specified by user
     * @param size the size of the Stack
     */
    public DiscardPile(int size){
        //this.data = (T[]) new Object[size];
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public int getSize(){ // getter
        return this.size;
    }
```

If I input 10 instead of 52, it works just fine without an error at the end (since there are 10 Cards), if I input 0, it just doesn't print.

I am also supposed to write a call to the removeTopCards method. and test the method by passing a reference to a card whose integer value is 20. The output should look like this
look like in this order.

```
9 of Diamonds
A of Diamonds
K of Spades
8 of Diamonds
4 of Spades
```

I know I must do it like

```
discardPile.removeTopCard(new Card(20));
```

but I don't know how I'd go about printing it through a for loop. Maybe it should be done like this?

```
for(int j = 0; j < discardPile.getSize(); j++) {
    Card vari = discardPile.push(); 
    //pushes the already popped cards onto a stack?
                System.out.println(vari.getRankAsString() + " of " + vari.getSuitAsString());
```

I know this is quite lengthy but any help would be appreciated. I'm a beginner to JAVA and this is my first time really dealing with stacks of any form.

Comment: Hi @Lost Soul, I wanted to suggest a couple things you could do to get more answers, faster. Your question includes detailed code, which is good, but it doesn't include all *relevant* code. For example, if you want help figuring out why an `EmptyStackException` is being thrown, it would be very helpful to see what the `isEmpty()` method is, but you did not include it. Second, your question is long, but the real problem is that it asks multiple things (fixing the exception, printing in a loop, etc.). Please narrow it down to a single thing, with all relevant code

Comment: For more on how to write great questions, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)